# Z-index positioning not working properly

Tags: html, css, z-index, positioning

I have a container I want to make a `h2` appear aligned to the center with a slight line behind it. What I can't do is to make the line go behind the `h2` box. No matter what I try, it keeps crossing **over** the h2 box.

Here goes a sample of what I need to accomplish:
[image]

Any help appreciated.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h2>H2 needs to be centered</h2>
    <div class="line-section-header"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The css I'm using is:

```
h2 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-family: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 140px;
    color: #3F3F3F;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 999;
}


.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #white;
}

.section-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.line-section-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: For `z-index` to work you need to give the element `position: relative|absolute|fixed`.

Comment: Html please then we can help :)

Comment: Please post the HTML code you currently have and let us know some of the steps you have attempted. We can then work to get you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi @AjayMakwana there is the piece of html as well as the css.

@user3262111 I have tried to absolute position the line behind the `h2` and to set the `h2` index to a high number so it would be over the thin line, but it didn't work, the line keeps crossing through the `h2` block.

Comment: Hi guys, you all really helped me out here. Thank you so much!
Have a great day everyone.

Comment: check answers is solved:)

Answer (score 2):

I made a sample. check my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/amitv1093/r3arp2m8/

html

```
<div class="container">

  <h2>  h2 </h2>
  <div class="line"> </div>

</div>
```

css

```
.container
{
  position:relative;
text-align:center;
 background:#d9d9d9;
  z-index:-99;
  padding:12px 0px;
}

h2
{
width:100px;  
background:grey;
height:50px;
text-align:center;
  margin:0px auto;
  line-height:50px;

}

.line
{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
  top:50%;
  margin:1px 0px;  
  z-index:-9;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> h2 {  //other props  position: relative; }

Answer (score 1):

alignment will be dynamic as container height

```css
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #white;
}

.section-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-family: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 140px;
    color: #3F3F3F;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
}
.line-section-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h2>H2 needs to be centered</h2>
    <div class="line-section-header"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Valeu, cara! :-DD

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
}

.line-section-header {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this in css:

```
h2 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-family: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 140px;
    color: #3F3F3F;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 420px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
}


.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #white;
    position: relative;
}

.section-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.line-section-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    margin-top: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```